# How do I post JSON data using Spring's RestTemplate?

Tags: json, resttemplate

I don't quite understand how to solve my particular situation given the examples I have found. I am trying to post a JSON string to a URL to create a new object. The response from the REST Service is a URI to the newly created resource. The REST call is suppose to look like this:

```
http://www.some.url.com/REST/create?data={ "param1":"value1", "param2":"value2", ... }
```

So what are my parameters based upon the example above? Is it something like this?

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
URI uri = restTemplate.postForLocation("http://www.some.url.com/REST/create?data=", "{ "param1":"value1", "param2":"value2", ... }");
```

I currently have all the param/value pairs in a Map which can be easily transformed to JSON using Jackson. In this case can I do the following:

```
Map<String, String> record = new HashMap<String, String>();
record.put("param1","value1");
record.put("param2","value2");

URI uri = restTemplate.postForLocation("http://www.some.url.com/REST/create?data=", record);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

easy way to this this

```
public static String callService(String url, Map<String, String> data) throws Exception 
{RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response= rest.postForEntity(url, data, String.class);
            System.out.println(response.getBody()); 
}
```